# tag for access outlook add new contact page from html/aspx

Tags: html

Like the "mailto:" keyword in hyperlink (this opens clients outlook's email sending page (window)), what should be the keyword or tag for open the cleint's outlook's add new contact's window from html ?

Comment: it does not open outlook email client .. it opens the associated email application ..
Email is internet related and that is why there is a protocol about it.. contacts are not ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such keyword. The `mailto:` is a defined standard to open the client's default E-Mail application. There is nothing similar related to the local contacts list.

This *may* be possible in Internet Explorer using proprietary VBScript and specific security settings - but it also may not.

Comment: ok thanks. I want to open the vCard which is generated by code directly in the outlook. how come i do this?

Comment: @Lalit you could serve it as a VCF file download, that would open it in whatever program is configured to do it on the client's machine.

Comment: No..no ... I don't want to serve it fro download. in fact it will automatically save on server in file system. I just want to pick it from that file location programmatically and open directly in the outlook porcess. how to do this??

Comment: @Lalit what exactly do you mean by "picking" it from that location, copy?

Comment: come on... see, I will create the vcf file in some location means like "c://MyvcfFiles/myvcf.vcf" like this. then want to map path programmatically  the created vcf file from the "c://MyvcfFiles/myvcf.vcf" path. and it will be open directly in the outlook. clear sir?

Comment: @Lalith no, not clear. What is the server here, and what is the client? Where exactly are you generating the vcf file? How does the client have access to it?